# Is there a way to skip one row during Data migration from Oracle to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am working on Data migration from Oracle to Redshift and want to apply the transformation rule to skip one row. I know we can use remove column but not row. Anyone can give me any suggestions if I can there is a way to skip a row?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct inbuilt way to skip row from using DMS .
There is one thing that you can do is filter operation on column .
If you have a column where you can define range i.e integer column in source data table.
Oracle has one N tile query that will sort table in order .
Once you have range defined then you can split your DMS task based on ranges and skip the row that you want .

[DMS Source Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.Filters.html)

Sample example for skipping row 3 here

```
{
                          "rule-type": "table-settings",
                          "rule-id": "4",
                          "rule-name": "4",
                          "object-locator": {
                            "schema-name": "abc",
                            "table-name": "table1"
                          },
                          "parallel-load": {
                            "type": "ranges",
                            "columns": [
                              "ID"
                            ],
                            "boundaries": [
                              [
                                "Row1"
                              ],
                              [
                                "Ro2"
                              ],
                              [
                                "Row4"
                              ],
                              [
                                "Ro5"
                              ]
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
```